# Problem with Old Facebook JavaScript SDK

Tags: facebook

I have an issue with the old sdk. Whenever I try to authorize a new user I get redirected to the home page of my app in the iframe. However, after I close the iframe and refresh the page, I can easily authorize a user. 
But whenever I delete the application from my facebook account and try to authorize it, I'm back to the previous problem.

I've noticed the same bug in the different web applications. Hootsuite could be a good example.

Did facebook change the old api or did they change the authorization proces lately ?

Answer (score 0):

I have a bug report open with Facebook for this.  Go add your comment and vote it up.

http://bugs.developers.facebook.net/show_bug.cgi?id=12260

Comment: I actually fixed the error by just switching to the new javascript SDK. If you don't want to wait for facebook's fix. You might do the same as well. All I know is that this issue is quite an old one. It's been a month or so.

Comment: I actually did the same, although I'm still trying to push for more support on the ticket.  Some people can't rewrite their apps as easy as we could.